# Does doped semiconductor have free electrons at 0K?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, solar-cells

For intrinsic semiconductors, they don't have any free electrons at conduction band at 0k and behave like insulators. But if doped, let's say n-type doped, they will have extra electrons which do not have chemical bond to restrict them.

Will these doped semiconductors behave like metal conductors, or even "superconductors" at 0K?

Answer (score 1):

Dopants in a semiconductor require a small thermal energy to ionize. Without this energy, an electron donor atom will just keep its electron, and an acceptor atom will keep its hole. So at 0 K, a semiconductor will be an insulator, doped or not.